# Can I use 3 LEDs with R, G and B color to illuminate the scene to obtain better color reproduction?

Tags: optics

To obtain high color image quality, 3CMOS is used to capture R, G and B color which is separated by prism. If I illuminate the scene using 3 LEDs with R, G and B color respectively, can I obtain a high color image quality image? Is there any requirements on LEDs?

Answer (score 1):

The answer might depend on what you mean by, "high quality."

Your camera will capture *less* color information if the emission spectrum of your red, blue, and green light sources is narrower than the spectrum that is admitted by each of the camera's three color filters.

But sometimes, as they say, "less is more." It depends on what quality of the scene you are hoping to capture. The whole idea of any filter in image processing is to throw away "information" that is not interesting, in order to make the information that is interesting more visible.

Color vision and the capturing and faithful rendering of color images are surprisingly deep subjects.

To learn more, you could start with either of these articles:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_rendering_index

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamerism_(color)

Comment: I'd agree that color rending is anything but "simple." With just 3 LED's? Maybe but you'd probably need more to get enough light. I'd have said the main point another way. By adjusting the illumination of the R, G and B LED's you could achieve any color temperature that you want. You could also achieve "unnatural" colors such as all B, or just G and B.

Comment: @MaxW, my point is, you could make a "yellow" ink that looks bright yellow to your eye and, to the camera when it is illuminated with "white" light, but it might look dark when illuminated by a combination of narrow-band red, narrow-band green, and narrow-band blue light sources. That would be an example of [metameric failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamerism_(color)#Metameric_failure).

Comment: @MaxW, LEDs can be pretty bright these days, and cameras can be very sensitive, but I was interpreting "3 LEDs" to mean a number of different colors, rather than a number of individual emitters.

Comment: Maybe I understand you. The spectrum of R LED should look like color matching function of R component of CIE color space? However 3 CMOS camea uses one prism to separate white light into R/G/B light. Does the spectrum of separated R light should look like color matching function?

Comment: Yes. Here 3 LEDs mens three kinds of LEDs.  If I just hope to capture human teeth and surrounding gum, does the method work? For the specific application, the color is limited.